# Optional trailing slash mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a very specific problem.
The title gives a lot of other questions that have correct answers, however I don't know how to fit this to my own rewrite rules.

My .htaccess looks like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^[^/]*/?$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/dev/zeroyear/$)
RewriteRule ^dev/zeroyear/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ /dev/zeroyear/index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [L,QSA]
```

I want the following 2 URLs to redirect to the same page:

```
http://timesheep.name/dev/zeroyear/news
http://timesheep.name/dev/zeroyear/news/
```

The last rewrite rule is causing a 500 because of the question mark I put, but the logs say nothing. If I change it to this:

```
RewriteRule ^dev/zeroyear/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ /dev/zeroyear/index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [L,QSA]
```

The error goes away, but http://timesheep.name/dev/zeroyear/news will return a 404.

What can I do about this?

Comment: I think I am missing something... to me, the original rule and what you have as the change are the same. What is the change you made?

Comment: @Wige Yes, I made a little typo, that is now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a mix of non-greedy matches (which will eat up optional `/`'s) and optional `/`'s all mixed together. Try separating them into distinct matches:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/dev/zeroyear/$)
RewriteRule ^dev/zeroyear/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+?)/?$ /dev/zeroyear/index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/dev/zeroyear/$)
RewriteRule ^dev/zeroyear/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+?)/?$ /dev/zeroyear/index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/dev/zeroyear/$)
RewriteRule ^dev/zeroyear/([^/]+)/([^/]+?)/?$ /dev/zeroyear/index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/dev/zeroyear/$)
RewriteRule ^dev/zeroyear/([^/]+?)/?$ /dev/zeroyear/index.php?var1=$1 [L,QSA]
```